# How can I format LocalDateTime to present it in JSP view

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

I'm going to format LocalDateTime value in JSP view. I'm using Spring and Java 8. Now my view displays LocalDateTime value: "2016-08-05T22:19:05.034" but I would like to print date in format like these "2016-08-05 22:19:05" or "2016-08-05".

I have done some resarch and I see that using 
**<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>** is suitable only for old Date type not for LocalDateTime. So I decided to convert LocalDateTime in Date but at this point it dosen't display anything.

```
<p>
<strong>Time on end:</strong> ${auction.endTime}  // too much details displayed
<c:set var="timeEnds" value="${Date.from(auction.startTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())}" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${timeEnds}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
</p>
```

So what am I doing wrong? How I can resolve this problem in the easiest way?

Comment: **Never use `LocalDateTime` when you mean a specific moment.** Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, the class does *not* represent a point on the timeline. Instead, use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`. Your call to `atZone` returns a `ZonedDateTime` (not a `LocalDateTime`), and is likely what you want to be displaying to the user.

Answer (score 4):

My alternative, create a second getter method in its class which returns the formatted date as below:

```
public String getFormattedDate(){
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd 
HH:mm:ss");
        return getOriginalDate().format(formatter);
}
```